# Seeking data of worldwide shore lines and bathymetry?

Tags: data, geolocation

Is there a free database with all geolocations for shorelines?

Is there a free database for near-shore bathymetry data?

Comment: There is another SE for open data [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/). Is there a specific area you are looking for?

Comment: Optimal are all shore lines of the world, arctica and antarctica dont have to be included though.

Answer (score 4):

Natural Earth project has these datasets and many more: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/

To use the data you could:

1. Download QGIS,
2. Download the dataset and unzip it.
3. Drag and drop the .tiff (geotiff raster files) and .shp (shapefile vector files) into the opened QGIS window.

All the data uses the standard projection 4326 so no headaches mixing any of the datasets

Answer (score 3):

You could use OpenStreetMap coastlines.

The data is provided by Jochen Topf from here as a shapefile free of charge: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/.

Please consider the the ODbL license when working with OpenStreetMap data.